# I think I'm misinterpreting Unity3d's Hierarchy system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hierarchy

So I have a class called Enemy, Player, and Gamemanager. I set up my Unity Hierarchy system (on the left side of unity under the name "Hierarchy") like so:

```
Enemy (1) 
Enemy (2) 
Enemy (3) 
Enemy (4) 
Enemy (5) 
Player (1) 
GameManager;
```

But when I put `void Start () { Debug.Log(this);}` (on each of the classes) I get this

```
Enemy (1) 
Enemy (5) 
Enemy (3) 
GameManager; 
Enemy (2)
Player (1) 
Enemy (4)
```

What gives? What's the point of the Hierarchy system if it doesn't change when the objects are loaded? Is there anyway I can make it so I can get the first result, when I do `void Start (Debug.Log(this))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following good programming practices, the execution order shouldn't matter.

However, there are a lot of beginner game developers using Unity, which might explain why they added Script Execution Order to the project settings.

> By default, the Awake, OnEnable and Update functions of different
>   scripts are called in the order the scripts are loaded (which is
>   arbitrary). However, it is possible to modify this order using the
>   Script Execution Order settings (menu: Edit > Project Settings >
>   Script Execution Order).

More information is available here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html